# How will the UK Commons debate on the 3rd of September despite the prorogation?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, house-of-commons

[image]
Graphic via *"Prorogation: How can the government suspend Parliament?"* [BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-48936711)

If the Commons is [suspended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prorogation_in_the_United_Kingdom#Boris_Johnson_in_2019), how is it they will be [debating tonight](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-49570682), the 3rd of September?

---

Edit: I kept misreading the calendar as August for some reason, apologies.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [order authorising prorogation](https://privycouncil.independent.gov.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/2019-08-28-List-of-Business-2.pdf) states that:

> It is this day ordered by Her Majesty in Council that the Parliament be prorogued 
>   on a day **no earlier than Monday the 9th day of September and no later than Thursday 
>   the 12th day of September 2019** to Monday the 14th day of October 2019

Hence prior to that date, Parliament may sit.